# Value of type '[String]' has no member 'joinWithSeparator'

Tags: arrays, swift, directory

I want to build a request URL with params directory with swift Here is the code:

```
static func Get<T:Codable>(codePoint: String, param: Dictionary<String, NSObject>, completion:@escaping(T?) -> Void){
    let paramsStr = "?" + param.map{"\($0)=\($1)"}.joinWithSeparator("&")        
    Get(codePoint: codePoint + paramStr, completion: completion)

}
```

The main idea is to map the directory to an array of string and then join them using '&' but Xcode complain that there is no `joinWithSeparator` method with `[String]` what I have done wrong?

[image]

Comment: It's now been renamed to `joined(separator: "&")`

Comment: @Sweeper thanks for pointing that out, things are working now

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in the docs, look for `joined(separator:)` details at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1690077-joined